# Questions about operators in java?

Tags: java, operators

I have 1 class:

```
public class Prog3 {
public static void main(String[] arg){
    int k = 0, i = 0;
    boolean r , t = true;
    r = (t & 0 < (i +=1));
    r = (t && 0 < (i +=2));
    r = (t | 0 < (k +=1));
    r = (t || 0 < (k +=2));
    System.out.println( i+ "  " + k);
   }

}
```

Why are the results of the program are: 3 1

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper, work it out by hand. Once that is done post why you think it should be different than what you got.

Comment: Note : & is different from &&. Read more about "bitwise" and "logical" operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are short circuit operators, this means:

- in `&&`, if left side is `false`, right side is not evaluated.
- in `||`, if left side is `true`, right side is not evaluated.

While `&` and `|` are bitwise operators, this means both sides are always evaluated.

With this at hand, let's perform each operation:

```
r = (t & 0 < (i +=1));
//true & i +=1 -> i = 1
r = (t && 0 < (i +=2));
//true && i+=2 -> i = 3
r = (t | 0 < (k +=1));
//true | k +=1 -> k = 1
r = (t || 0 < (k +=2));
//true || ... no need to evaluate right side
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I have a questions seem a bit silly: Operator `<` precedence over operator`&&`. I think the expression `(t | | 0 <(k + = 2))` will be done similar expressions `(t + 0 * (k + = 2))`. So `0 <(k + = 2)` will be carried out before and `k` values ​​will be increased I did something wrong. :)

Comment: @vanphuc.iv boolean operators are evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

| pipe is bitwise operator.so it will try to execute both condition even if first is true.
While || pipe will not check for rest of condition if any of prior condition becomes true.
value of i becomes 3 because && will be true only if all condition becomes true.

r = (**t** & **0 < (i +=1)**)

r = (**t** && **0 < (i +=2)**)

r = (**t** | **0 < (k +=1)**)

r = (**t** || 0 < (k +=2))

Condition in bold will be executed.